# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, already exported default withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page component `SimulationReport` that I want to redirect to upon clicking a button from the `Reports` page component. This is the `App` component with the `Router`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Ratings} />
          <Route path="/LeagueSettings" component={LeagueSettings} />
          <Route path="/Fixtures" component={Fixtures} />
          <Route path="/Reports" component={Reports} />
          <Route path="/SimulationReport" component={SimulationReport} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And here are the relevant code bits from `Reports` which is a function component:

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

<td>
   <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSimView(index)}>
   View
   </Button>
</td>

  const handleSimView = index => e => {
    console.log("index: " + index);
    loadSimulationResult(simulationIds[index]);
    props.history.push("/SimulationReport");
  };
```

And at the end of the file I have this:

```
export default withRouter(Reports);
```

Upon clicking the button, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to redirect this? Or maybe I should be doing it a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your prop `history` is not being passed from the `<Route>` tag in your  component.
You can pass props to a Route Rendered Component by doing the following line:

```
<Route
 path='/SimulationReport'
 render={(props) => <SimulationReport {...props} history={yourHistoryObjectForTheRouter} />}
/>
```

where ***yourHistoryObjectForTheRouter*** would be your custom history exported object.

**EDIT**: Updated code

***UPDATE TO ANSWER TO ADDRESS OP's NEEDS:***

1° Alright, so first you'll need to install the package called `history` to your React Application. (You can use `npm i history` or `yarn add history`. It depends on what you have installed. If you don't know what's *yarn* then use the *npm* option)

2° Somewhere in your project inside the ***App*** folder *(src/App/)*, you're going to create another folder called `history` and inside `index.js`.
The contents of the `index.js` file are going to be the next ones.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({});
```

3° Once that is done, head to your `App/index.js` file, where you have your `<Router>` main tag. If you've done everything as I stated before, in that `App/index.js` you're going to add a new import:

```
import history from "./history";
```

Which is your new Custom History Object.

***Here you can choose two paths of how you want to solve your problem***

=== *First Solution*

4° Scroll down in that same file, until you find your `<Router></Router>` tag, and you're going to update it to this next part:

```
<Router>
   <NavigationBar />
    <Sidebar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Ratings} />
      <Route path="/LeagueSettings" component={LeagueSettings} />
      <Route path="/Fixtures" component={Fixtures} />
      <Route path="/Reports" component={Reports} />
      <Route
          path='/SimulationReport'
          render={(props) => <SimulationReport {...props} history= 
              {history} />}
      />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

After this, you'll have your Custom History Object setted up and your component now should work.
This solution however will only work for that specific component Route, and that means that you will have to do the same for the other `<Route >` that require the use of the history object.

Stop here if you choose this solution.

=== *Second Solution*

This solution is better, because you'll now have access to your history object globally, just with an import.

4° Scroll down in that same file, until you find your `<Router></Router>` tag, and you're going to update it to this next part:

```
<Router history={history}> //Here's the change
   <NavigationBar />
    <Sidebar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Ratings} />
      <Route path="/LeagueSettings" component={LeagueSettings} />
      <Route path="/Fixtures" component={Fixtures} />
      <Route path="/Reports" component={Reports} />
      <Route path="/SimulationReport" component={SimulationReport} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

After this, you'll have your Custom History Object setted up.

5° Navigate to the file that contains the `Reports` functional component, and on the imports at the top of your file, you're going to import the same `history` as you did in `App/index.js`. Beware that depending on the level of subfolders that your Reports components is in, it's how the import is going to change. It can end up like this:

`import history from "../history";`
or this
`import history from "../../history";`
it depends or even more "../". It depends on your subfolder levels

After that, you'll need to update your function `handleSimView` so instead of doing this:

```
const handleSimView = index => e => {
    console.log("index: " + index);
    loadSimulationResult(simulationIds[index]);
    props.history.push("/SimulationReport");
  };
```

do this:

```
const handleSimView = index => e => {
    console.log("index: " + index);
    loadSimulationResult(simulationIds[index]);
    history.push("/SimulationReport"); //Change is here, removed "props."
  };
```

After this, your code should work. This solution you can implement it everywhere as you would only need to import the history object and just use it.

I'll be waiting to hear from you to see if it worked. If anything else happens, you can ask me.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Maldonado So, in this case... what would `yourHistoryObjectForTheRouter` be? I'm quite new to React so still getting to grips with the concepts.

Comment: yourHistoryObjectForTheRouter is a custom history object that you can use to push locations in your app, without having to refresh the application. In your case you're trying to push your current View of the app to "/simulationreport" which won't work right now, because you need a custom history object to do that. Let me update my Answer with the things that you need.

Comment: @clattenburgcake

Comment: I updated my answer! Hope it helps, if you need anything else, just ask me!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful for me. I will have a look at the solution and try to solve this issue.

Comment: @AlanMaldonaldo I've gone with the second solution, it looks like the browser URL updates upon `handleSimView`, so it becomes `localhost:3000/simulationreport`... but it does not actually redirect me to the page `SimulationReport` for some reason... Would you happen to know why this is the case?

Comment: Does the console gives you any error? Perhaps your import of the SimulationReport component is enclosed in `{}` and it shouldn't be like that. it should be something like `import SimulationReport from ...` instead of `import {SimulationReport} from ...`

Comment: Nevermind, I know whats happening. In your `App/index.js`, update the path of every `<Route>` to be undercase, and also add the prop `exact`, for example: `<Route path="/simulationreport" exact component={SimulationReport} />`. After that, go to the file where you use the `history.push` and change the path there to the exact match. So it would look like this `history.push("/simulationreport")`. If it doesn't work, reach to me again.

Comment: @AlanMaldonaldo thanks so much, it's working now :)